# Using a function directly or by declaring it to a variable

Tags: javascript

I'm new to software development and trying to understand the basics of JavaScript. In the code below, if I write iterator.next() instead of charAt in "while", the result changes. Can you explain this to me why does it only return 1 when I type iterator.next directly?

```js
  const str = '123';
  const iterator = str[Symbol.iterator]()

  let charAt = iterator.next()

  while (!charAt.done) {
    console.log(charAt.value)
    charAt = iterator.next()
    // output: "1"
    //         "2"
    //         "3"
  }
```

```js
  const str = '123';
  const iterator = str[Symbol.iterator]()

  let charAt = iterator.next()

  while (!iterator.next().done) {
    console.log(charAt.value)
    charAt = iterator.next()
    // output: "1"
  }
```

Comment: FWIW I wouldn't really call user-defined iterables as "the basics of JavaScript". But YMMV I suppose.

Comment: We say that `next()` "consumes" a value. Every time you call `next()` a value is consumed, independently if you'll get the value or not

Answer (score 2):

It's easier to see if you have a longer string.

```js
  const str = '12345678';
  const iterator = str[Symbol.iterator]()

  let charAt = iterator.next()

  while (!iterator.next().done) {
    console.log(charAt.value)
    charAt = iterator.next()
    // output: "1"
  }
```

Because you call `next()` in two different places inside the loop (as well as once outside the loop), every time you go around the loop, you advance two places.

Answer (score 1):

- u have used iterator.next() three times,
- for the fitst time it returs 1, which u assign to charAt,
- then in while loop condition iterator.next() returns 2, but u have not assigned it any where,
- and because u have not updated your charAt value yet, it logs 1,
- then iterator.next() returns 3, which u assign to charAt,
- but in second pass of while loop iterator.next() returns {done:true}, and the control doesn't goes inside loop